# Change input background to transparent in Safari

Tags: input, background, transparent

Is it possible to eliminate the white background (via CSS) in the input and textareas when you click in the field using Safari or any other browser?  Here is my link: [link text](http://www.erikrp.com/contact.htm)

Cheers.

Erik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `:focus` rule overrides it. Make another rule that's more specific to counter that?

```
.postcard input:focus, textarea:focus {
    background:url("/img/pixel.gif") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
```